# How to optimize this code (finding closest string in anther column)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization

I need help with my exercise. I have two data frames and I need to find original Latin names for the names in the first data frame.

I have managed to write this code and it works if the list is small, but my original list has much more data, more then 10 000 items in one of the lists and around 600 in another, and the code just goes on and on and gives nothing. In other words it is inefficient and unusable for bigger data.

I have tried to use numpy arrays hoping it can help, but it did not help. I am still a beginner, so I know there must be a way to write it better, but I am stuck figuring out how.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import textdistance

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'name': ['Peter', 'Victor', 'Claudio']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'name_in_latin': ['Claudius', 'Petrus', 'Victor']})

name_list = []


for row in df1.itertuples():
    name_list.append(row.name)


np_sub_list = np.array([v for v in name_list])

lac_list = []

for row in df2.itertuples():
    lac_list.append(row.name_in_latin)

words = []
np_lac_list = np.array([v for v in lac_list])


for s1 in np_sub_list:
    for s2 in np_lac_list:
        if textdistance.levenshtein(s1, s2) <= 3:
            words.append((s1, s2))

for w in words:
    print(w)

#The output is ok:
#('Peter', 'Petrus')
#('Victor', 'Victor')
#('Claudio', 'Claudius')
```

Names paired with their Latin version is what I want, but how to make it work for a much bigger list?

Comment: Wrapping everything into `np.array` isn't going to make it faster when you still need to iterate through element by element. Speeding up would require vectorisation. Perhaps make a large dataset with all your possible matches in two different columns and then do a column-on-column distance measure

Answer (score 0):

Try cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) on axis 1, then filter down with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) + [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates):

```
df3 = df1[['name']].merge(df2[['name_in_latin']], how='cross')
df3['dist'] = df3.apply(lambda r: textdistance.levenshtein(*r), axis=1)
df3 = df3.sort_values('dist').drop_duplicates('name')
```

`df3`:

```
      name name_in_latin  dist
5   Victor        Victor     0
6  Claudio      Claudius     2
1    Peter        Petrus     3
```

Optional convert to a list of tuples:

```
words = list(df3[['name', 'name_in_latin']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

`words`:

```
[('Victor', 'Victor'), ('Claudio', 'Claudius'), ('Peter', 'Petrus')]
```

---

Explainations

Cross Merge to get all values to compare in rows:

```
      name name_in_latin
0    Peter      Claudius
1    Peter        Petrus
2    Peter        Victor
3   Victor      Claudius
4   Victor        Petrus
5   Victor        Victor
6  Claudio      Claudius
7  Claudio        Petrus
8  Claudio        Victor
```

Calculate Distance:

```
      name name_in_latin  dist
0    Peter      Claudius     8
1    Peter        Petrus     3
2    Peter        Victor     4
3   Victor      Claudius     8
4   Victor        Petrus     6
5   Victor        Victor     0
6  Claudio      Claudius     2
7  Claudio        Petrus     7
8  Claudio        Victor     7
```

Then sort so smallest distances are first, and drop duplicate names to keep only the smallest of each.